# "The page you requested was not found" for member templates

Tags: templates, upgrade

After update to 2.9.2 I have "The page you requested was not found" for all member pages(registration, profile and so on).
Can't understand what's wrong. I've checked .htaccess rules - ok, templates for member pages also exists. So how to fix this?

Best regards, Aleksey.

Comment: Alur did you find a solution to this? I might have a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, check the 'themes/profile_themes/{you site profile folder}'. In my case I forgot to copy this folder after site was updated.